# Tomcat started but Eclipse seems unable to detect that

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat v5.0.30 inside Eclipse Helios, installed with "Server->New...".

Tomcat starts correctly, but Eclipse seems unable to detect that the server is started, so the "starting Tomcat" status bar keeps spinning until start timeout is reached and Tomcat is shutted down.

As a workaround I set the Tomcat start timeout to a very big value, but obviously I'd like to work normally.

As suggested in other questions I used netstat -ano to find if the server port was being used by another process, but the port resulted free. In any case, I also tried to change Tomcat port to other values, but it didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe it just takes tomcat that long to start? Try removing all webapps from tomcat to see if the startup is faster.

Comment: I assure not. Tomcat timeout is set to 10000 and still expires. Also, Tomcat effectively starts and the web application deployed to it is available after a few seconds, but Eclipse seem not to notice that.

Comment: Anyone has a solution? I am having the same problem with my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue in my case it helped to switch connector protocol from

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol" ...>
```

to

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...>
```